# How can I serve a pdf file via the Google Docs API from nodejs (without saving a file)?

Tags: node.js, express, pdf, google-docs-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I am trying to serve a PDF file via a Nodejs Express server from the Google Docs API (For context it's a resume). I am able to accomplish this with HTML, text, and rtf files easily. I cannot accomplish this with PDF and other formats like zip, doc (perhaps because they are binary file types)

macOS Mojave | 
nodejs v10.15.0 | 
express.js v4.17.0 | 
Chrome v74.0.3729.157

---

I initially setup the Google Docs API and called the `drive.files.export` function with text/plain, then passed the result.data (the string of plain-text version of my resume) in res.send. This worked √

Next, I did the same, but I set headers `res.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=resume.txt");` , and again it worked; I could download a text file in my browser. √

I tried the same thing yet again, this time passing 'application/rtf' to Google Docs API and then setting the appropriate headers in my response, and I was able to get an rtf version of my resume. √

Here's where things stopped working for me...

The next logical step was to do the same with PDF, setting all the headers as I did with RTF. The downloaded file was of roughly the size I'd expect it to be and I didn't get any errors in Nodejs, but the file was not valid (couldn't open with any application). I tried the same with .doc, .zip and a couple others. No luck.

I have read articles where people are piping the data into a write stream and saving a file to their server. I do not want to do this.

The majority of other resources are explaining how to download public pdf files from a public folder on the server. Also not what I'm after.

When I console log the response object from Google Docs, I get an object that contains a bunch of request header and file meta data, as well as containing a 'data' object with all the raw data. Text formats' data looked as expected as human readable data, and binary formats' data looks like gibberish as expected.

The closest I got to any progress was when I was experimenting with .zip format and I was able to download a zip archive that I could (only) unzip via terminal, it would produce a blank file but at least with the correct name. This is likely because the zip file contains plain-text instructions about the files it contains, and therefore was not corrupted.

---

Working example code for RTF files:

```
router.get("/rtf", (req, res) => {
  const docData = googleapi.getGoogleDocs("application/rtf");
  docData.then(dd => {
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/rtf");
    res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=resume.rtf");
    res.send(dd.data);
  });
});
// ... some auth stuff, Promises, etc ...
getGoogleDocs(mimeType) {
  return drive.files
    .export({
      fileId: "XxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXx",
      mimeType: mimeType
    })
    .then(fileData => {
      return fileData;
    });
}
```

I have tried some various thing to get the same success with PDF. Pretty much all combinations result in a downloaded file that is not-valid/corrupt:

```
router.get("/pdf", (req, res) => {
  const docData = googleapi.getGoogleDocs("application/pdf");
  docData.then(dd => {
    // Tried various headers:
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
    // res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
    res.setHeader(
      "Content-Disposition",
      "attachment; filename=resume_html.zip"
    );
    // Setting the content length based on the meta-data from
    // the Google Docs API payload
    res.setHeader("Content-Length", "476");
    // Tried various ways to send the response:
    // res.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
    res.end(dd.data, "binary");
  });
});
```

..and the modified code around the call to Google Docs API...

```
  const aPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    drive.files.export(
      {
        fileId: "XxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXx",
        mimeType: mimeType
      },
      { encoding: null },
      (err, buffer) => {
        // There were no errors.
        err ? reject(err) : resolve(buffer);
        // return buffer;
      }
    );
  });
  return aPromise;
```

The addition of 'encoding: null' was suggested as a way to prevent corrupting binary data. I'm not sure how that would help given the data is inside a response object in string format.

---

Expected result: I can download a working PDF file.

Actual Result: I get a file which contains data received from the Google Docs API, presumably raw PDF data, but it doesn't result in downloading a valid/recognizable pdf file.

Comment: I have the same problem